# How to call a route from controller in laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

TestController

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Users::all();
    return view('welcome', compact('data'));
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
```

How can i call that route in my controller?
I want to return  route from index of my controller not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Use [redirect to route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-named-routes):

```
return redirect()->route('mainpage');
```

And it's also a good idea to add a name to a root route:

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index')->name('mainpage');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
return redirect()->route('/');
```

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-named-routes